# бесконечный цикл (scanf), не понимаю почему

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num;

    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if (num >= 1 && num <= 2000)
        {
            // Ниже тело цикла --------------------------
            if (num <= 4)
            {
                printf("few\n");
            }
            else if (num <= 9)
            {
                printf("several\n");
            }
            else if (num <= 19)
            {
                printf("pack\n");
            }
            else if (num <= 49)
            {
                printf("lots\n");
            }
            else if (num <= 99)
            {
                printf("horde\n");
            }
            else if (num <= 249)
            {
                printf("throng\n");
            }
            else if (num <= 499)
            {
                printf("swarm\n");
            }
            else if (num <= 999)
            {
                printf("zounds\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("legion\n");
            }
        } // закрывает "if (num >= 1 && num <= 2000)"
    } // закрывает "DO"

    while ((num < 1) || (num > 2000));
}
```

---

Как-то по-уродски код вставился...

Задача: На вход программа просит число. Если число в диапазоне от 1 до 2000, то следует выполнить тело цикла. И повторять это до тех пор, пока число меньше 1 или больше 2000.

В целом все работает. Проблемы возникают тогда, когда я ввожу не число. К примеру "q". Тогда программа будет бесконечно просить меня ввести что-то, и ей уже все ровно, что я ввожу нужные значения. Не понимаю, почему не работает. Мой взгляд на вещи:

1. Обьявляем переменную num
2. Запускаем цикл DO
3. Программа запрашивает данные (scanf)
4. Допустим я ввожу "q"
5. Т.к num - переменная типа int, я думаю до цикла if даже не дойдет
6. Проверка на завершения цикла while, но т.к условию num явно не удовлетворяет, то цикл идет заного
7. у меня опять запрашивают данные (scanf) и я ввожу "21"
8. На этом этапе значение num должно пройти в цикл if и цикл while должен завершиться т.к соблюдаются условия по выходу из цикла
9. вместо этого я получают цикл из бесконечных scanf....

и еще вопрос: почему я не получаю ошибку, когда пытаюсь ввести что-то, отличное от типа int? разве "&num" - это ни есть присвоение? всё уже должно было взорваться, когда я попытался впихнуть туда "q".

Comment: Для начала хотелось бы знать, в чем смысл этого бесконечного цикла while  ( (num < 1) || (num > 2000) );?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Почему бесконечного? При `num` от 1 до 2000 цикл завершается.

Comment: @Harry Я не разглядел, что это условие предыдущего цикла. Я думал, что это новое предложение.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно проверять, что возвращает `scanf`. Сделайте так:

```
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
    {
        while(fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
        continue;
    }
```

Т.е. пока не считано нормальное число - игнорировать введеннуюю строку и начать цикл заново...

У вас, встретив не цифру, `scanf` оставляет ее в буфере, и при повторении цикла опять встречает ее же...

Comment: Как-то сложно. Чем scanf не угодил?

Comment: @Qwertiy "Ну не люблю я его" (с) Конечно, это маловажно, особенно в данном случае, но у него и производительность пожиже - есть частный случай считывания до `'\n\`, вы же предлагаете, наверное, что-то с маской - типа `"%*[^\n]s"`, нет? Т.е. достаточно сложные и ненужные по сути внутренние разборки.

Comment: Я ж ответом написал, что я предлагаю ;) Но на мой взгляд `%*s` логичнее, чем до конца строки.

Comment: @Qwertiy А вдруг человек в сердцах наберет что-то типа `sesr 2fdrt 43gfhf!!!`? :)

Comment: А вдруг он просто `2fdrt 43gfhf!!!` наберёт?)

Comment: @Qwertiy :) Вобщем, как по мне - одно и то же можно сделать столькими разными способами, что считать какой-то один единственно верным не приходится...

Comment: Ну это-то да :)

Answer (score 2):

Вам следует проверять результат работы функции `scanf`, и если было введено не число, то пропускать введенные символы. Это можно сделать следующим образом

```
int num;

do
{
    int result = scanf( "%d", &num );

    if (result == EOF) break;

    if (result != 1)
    {
        scanf("%*[^\n]");
        num == 0;
    }

    if (num >= 1 && num <= 2000)
    {
        // Ниже тело цикла --------------------------
        if (num <= 4)
        {
            printf("few\n");
        }
        else if (num <= 9)
        {
            printf("several\n");
        }
        else if (num <= 19)
        {
            printf("pack\n");
        }
        else if (num <= 49)
        {
            printf("lots\n");
        }
        else if (num <= 99)
        {
            printf("horde\n");
        }
        else if (num <= 249)
        {
            printf("throng\n");
        }
        else if (num <= 499)
        {
            printf("swarm\n");
        }
        else if (num <= 999)
        {
            printf("zounds\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("legion\n");
        }
    } // закрывает "if (num >= 1 && num <= 2000)"
} while ((num < 1) || (num > 2000)); // закрывает "DO"
```

В этом фрагменте кода, если было введено не число, то функция `scanf` Ничего не считает, а потому лна возвратит значение 0. В этом случае данное `if` предложение пропустит все неправильно введенные символы

```
    if (result != 1)
    {
        scanf("%*[^\n]");
        num == 0;
    }
```

и вы сможете повторить итерацию цикла.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> scanf("%d", &num);
> ```

Если мы уверены, что никаких EOF пользователь не введёт, то нам надо дождаться ввода числа (scanf вернёт 1) выкидывая нечисловые значения (ведь мусор, лежащий в потоке, сколько не пытайся его читать, числом-то не становится):

```
while (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
  scanf("%*s");
```

Если мы хотим ещё и EOF проверять (который -1), то можно немного переписать условие:

```
while (scanf("%d", &num) == 0)
  scanf("%*s");
```

или

```
while (!scanf("%d", &num))
  scanf("%*s");
```

Если хочется порпускать всю строку целиком, то можно использовать

```
while (!scanf("%d", &num))
  scanf("%*[^\r\n]");
```

Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Да эта беда всегда была в scanf и им поэтому никто не пользуется, он выпихивает назад что ему не нравится по ungetc, короче надо строчку через gets ввести, а потом её в sscanf