# Обработка правильности ввода (язык С)

Tags: c, обработка

Необходимо обработать ввод:
Если введено число - все ОК.
Если не число, нужно ввести еще раз. И так до тех пор, пока не будет верный ввод.

```
'''
    int c;
        while (!scanf("%d", &c)) {
            printf("Wrong input!\n");
        }
'''
```

Если ввести "-", то все работает как надо, если ввести , например знак "=", то функция scanf перестает запускаться, выводится много раз "Wrong input!".
Кто знает, как обработать ввод правильно? И почему scanf так себя ведет?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [бесконечный цикл (scanf), не понимаю почему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/665231/%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-scanf-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83)

Comment: Формат `%d` пропускает пробелы и читает правильное (в т.ч. со знаком) целое число. Чтение символов прекращается, как только встретится **не цифра**. Т.о. в случае "Wrong input" вам надо прочесть и выбросить неправильные символы. Проще всего в таком случае читать в цикле посимвольно функцией `fgetc()`, пока не прочтете `\n` (или не поймаете EOF)

Comment: Попробуйте после вывода `printf` сбросить буфер ввода - например, прочесть все символы до первого встреченного символа конца строки `\n`, чтобы можно было начать сначала, а не читать непрочитанный неверный символ заново...

Answer (score -1):

Так работать не будет, получайте от пользователя строку, проверяйте введенные данные и потом конвертируйте в число.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* ... */
char с[20];
scanf("%s", &с);
int i = atoi( с );
scanf("%s", &с);
float f = atof( с );
printf("i = %d\n", i );
printf("f = %.6f\n", f );
printf("i * f = %.6f\n", i * f );
```

Comment: 1) В качестве имени символьного массива вы использовали кириллическую букву "эс". 2) Если `scanf` считает 20 или больше символов — поведение программы не определено. 3) Если считанное `atoi` число непредставимо типом `int`, то возвращаемое функцией `atoi` значение неопределено. 4) Если `atoi` не выполнит никаких преобразований, то вернёт ноль. [Пример](https://ideone.com/BVif5o). 5) `scanf` ожидает получить указатель на символьный тип, а вы передаёте ей `char (*)[20]` — поведение программы неопределено.

Comment: @wololo да я то умею пользоваться readline. Но в мое время он изучался по исходникам. Даже из литературы посоветовать нечего. А человек осваивает функцию scanf(), зачем ему порция жести? Это ж отобьёт желание учиться программировать.

Comment: Посмотрите пример из моего комментария. При неправильном вводе ваша програvма записывает `0` в переменную `i`.